# Subgroup Questions containing 8 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $Q$ be the subgroup of $H^*$ generated by the elements $i$, $j$, $k$. Let $N$ = {1, -1}. I am confused on what $H^*$ is exactly. Is it just an arbitrary subgroup of the units of Q, because that is what our other subgroups denoted with the '*' where. I need to show that $Q$ contains 8 elements......

Comment: Any thoughts? I just fixed a typo that may have caused concern.

Comment: Coming back also made me realise I hadn't sorted out the $^*$ notation thing. See Addendum 1 in my answer. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: I deleted a comment here because it was out of context and confusing. I have added a section on the units of the Hurwitz quaternions that I hope clarifies what they are.

Comment: You ask a lot of questions and get a lot of help but don't often accept answers. I'm curious as to why.

Comment: Thanks for your acknowledgement. This has caused me to reread my answer and there are one or two things that could do with clarifying or explaining better. Is there anything in my answer you'd like me to clarify or expand upon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with every type of notation in this regard. For example, sometimes $\mathbb R^* = \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$. Sometimes $^*$ indicates a dual space. It depends on the context.

In your case, I assume you are talking about matters related to quaternions.

If you take the linear span of $\{1, i, j, k\}$ over $\mathbb R$, you get a version of $\mathbb R^4$ which has a sensible multiplication defined on it, but it's skew and I guess $\mathbb H^*$ is a multiplicative group without the zero.

But, just looking at the elements $\{i, j, k\}$ with $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = −1$ you can generate an 8 element group by only including their unscaled products. It is the subgroup of $H^*$, of finite order cyclic elements.

Addendum 1: On the $^*$ notation thing, yes, if $A$ is a group, according to Serge Lang, in his book, Algebra 3rd Ed, $A^*$ is often used to denote the group of units of $A$. In the case of sets like

$$\mathbb K = \mathbb Q,\mathbb R,\ \mathbb C \text{ and } \mathbb H,\quad \mathbb K^* = \mathbb K \setminus \{0\}$$

as zero is the only non unit. H is sometimes used to mean the Hurwitz quaternions

$$H = \{a + bi + cj + dk \,|\, a, b, c, d \in \mathbb Z\ \text{ or } a, b, c, d \in \mathbb Z + 1/2\}$$

which is complicated. Note here that $H \neq \mathbb H$. However, the Lipschitz quaternions are

$$L = \{a + bi + cj + dk \,|\, a, b, c, d \in \mathbb Z\}$$

that is, just the simple integer span. In this case, where $Q$ is the group generated by non scaled products of $\{i, j, k\}$, $Q = L^*$ is a non trivial use of this notation.

Addendum 2: The units of H:

$$H^* = Q \cup \{\tfrac{1}{2}(\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k)\}$$

To get an inverse pair, it must be a conjugate pair. Conjugate by the quaternion definition. Here, $s, t, u, v$ are the signs, which can be either positive or negative freely in any combination.

$$(\frac{s1}{2}, \frac{ti}{2}, \frac{uj}{2}, \frac{vk}{2}) \text{ inverts } (\frac{s1}{2}, \frac{-ti}{2}, \frac{-uj}{2}, \frac{-vk}{2})$$

The usual mathematical way of writing this

$$(\pm\frac{1}{2}, \pm\frac{i}{2}, \pm\frac{j}{2}, \pm\frac{k}{2}) \text{ inverts } (\pm\frac{1}{2}, \mp\frac{i}{2}, \mp\frac{j}{2}, \mp\frac{k}{2})$$

can be confusing.

Comment: I've made significant edits to my original answer for the following reason: Addendum 1 elaborates on $^*$ notation. Addendum 2 presents the units of H.